# What is the name of this mathematical symbol in English?

Tags: mathematics, reading-aloud

[image]

The symbol looks like a mirrored capitalized E.
Because I don't know its name, I cannot Google for it.

Comment: It's a fair question since you would have to know Greek or math notation. Can be found [**here**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation) [**here**](http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/sigma-notation.html), and [**here**](http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/sigma-notation.html).

Comment: Note that almost all math symbols are Greek letters, so if you find another one you want to know the name of, just check the Greek alphabet: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_alphabet#Letters

Comment: Lists of mathematical symbols also help.  E.g., the capital sigma for summation that you're looking for is available in [this list](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols).  Something like [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) may help, too, although it won't necessarily tell you the name of the symbol, it may well help.

Comment: Your description *"mirrored capitalized E"* would more accurately describe the [existential quantification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existential_quantification) operator than the summation operator IMHO

Comment: @steeldriver Agreed but, if they hadn't given some indication of which symbol they were talking about, the question would be completely unclear.

Comment: Not relevant to the question, which is about the English language, but the equation in the question is incorrect (unless N=0). For example, taking k=2 makes the claim "N/2+N/4 = 2N", which is clearly false.

Comment: @DavidRicherby IMO the steeldriver comment remains fair: "mirrored" is confusing and should have been avoided, in favor of e.g. "malformed" or something similar. In the other hand, regarding your comment about the mathematical aspect, you're right. But I guess this formula is more an equation (looking for solution) rather than the expression of a "property" (asserting the equality). In fact, here, probably the solution is for `k = +&infin;`.

Comment: @cFreed Taking the limit of that sum as k goes to infinity gives N, not 2N.

Comment: @DavidRicherby As I said, it was only a guess. But now you make me think to it more precisely (and yet without searching for the true response), I (again :) guess you're right. So I wonder: because the OP clearly has no mathematical skills, sure he copied an existing formula he found somewhere, and we may expect it has a real signification. But what hell...?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It is an upper case [Sigma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigma), from the Greek alphabet.

It is almost always used to denote a [summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigma#Upper-case):

[image]

and is therefore (technically) called a [summation symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation), as others pointed out in the comments.

Comment: Yes! Therefore the usual English name of this mathematical symbol (in this context) is ___summation symbol___, _summation sign_, or _summation operator_. The related Unicode character for this use is ∑ (U+2211) and called _n-ary summation_ (where "n-ary" is a generic term generalizing "unary", "binary", "ternary" etc.). In contrast the usual Greek letter has another character Σ (U+03A3) which is called _Greek captal letter sigma_.

Comment: And read out loud (as part of a complete phrase, not pointing out the symbol itself) it's simply "sum". As in "The sum from *k* equals 0 to 5 of k"

Comment: While it's true that the symbol is a Greek capital sigma, it is much more appropriate to describe it as a summation sign.

Comment: @hobbs I thought it was "the sum of k from k equals 0 to 5"?

Comment: @Glorfindel "Because I don't know it's name, so I cannot google Google for it.  ". why you delete me "so" in this sentence. Am I wrong ?

Comment: @tox123 that's okay too :-P

Comment: @lovespring yes, it should be either this, or "I don't know it's name, so I cannot Google for it". The words "because" and "so" have the same function in this context.